# iOS guidelines archive

Tags: ios, ui, design

I'm researching historical changes of UI widgets.

Do you know if there's an archive with all the iOS interface guidelines published by Apple over the years?

Comment: Did you already contact Apple about this? Or tried archive.org?

Answer (score 1):

People rehost the PDFs everywhere. You can find PDFs of the interface guidelines just by searching for "**iOS interface guidelines pdf <year>**" on Google. For example, here's the [guidelines for 2011](http://tableless.github.io/exemplos/pdf/guidelines-interface-mobiles/MobileHIG.pdf). There's no official archive.